# Group various result selected from two different filter in grafana dashboard

Tags: grafana

Have a result dash board of table type and the data is filling up by selected two filter on it and I want to group them by one filter(please refer the image attached). Datasource is `influxDB`

1. Have filter name `scenario Id` which is a key for selecting a particular result data.
2. Second filter is `transaction name`

Current Dashboard is loading up data in the following manner,

[image]

Query I am using to fetch the data from the data source:

[image]

Transformation I am using on the current table result:

[image]

I am expecting the any one would fulfil my requirement (have show my two expectation). My table dashboard should show me result in any one format below,

[image]

How to achieve this ? Tried group by transformation but not working.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand: what do you have right now? Is it working? And what do you expect?

Comment: It is not working, I am trying to it in the table as per my expectation

Comment: Aha, I understand now. Basically, your query works, but you need to pivot it. It is better to do it on db's side (inside a query).

Comment: If you need help with that, I advise you to create a separate question, and provide it with your current query (as text!), current output, and expected output (preferably as text too). And don't forget to tag it as `influxdb` (and maybe `SQL`)